# JUNIT test for binary search tree

Tags: java, junit

I have implemented a binary search tree. Most of my test in JUNIT test is going through, including these two. I have implementedleavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() and insertValuesInAscendingOrderIncrementsHeight().

Both of these test goes through, however i do not know if it is correctly written based on what their description is asking.

//EDIT: I have added a test that might be a help to one of the test a need help with.

//TODO: help me understand if I have written the correct code for the test in insertValuesInAscendingOrderIncrementsHeight() and leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() based on what the description for the test is saying.

Have in mind, that I have not included all the tests in the test class, Because the goes through with my implementation of the tree.

Down here I have included my tree class and the test class with both the test I need help with.

```
/**
 * An Binary Search tree implementation.
 * @param <T>
 */
public class Tree <T extends Comparable <T>> implements BSTInterface <T>{
    private int size;
    private Node root;
    public class Node{
        private Node Left;
        private Node Right;
        private T data;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
        }
        public Node getRight(){
            return Right;
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return Left;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
    public Tree (){
        size = 0;
        root = null;
    }


    /**
     * Test for presence of a value.
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean search(T elem) {
        if(root == null ||elem == null){
        return false;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while(true){
            if(node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0){
                if(node.Right == null){
                    return false;
                } else{
                    node = node.Right;
                }
            } else if(node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0){
                break;
            } else{
                if(node.Left== null){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Add value to tree; duplicates are not allowed.
     * Return true if the element is not already present (and is thus inserted),
     * false otherwise.
     *
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean insert(T elem) {
        if (elem == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(elem);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while (true){
            if (node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                if (node.Right == null){
                    node.Right = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Right;
                }

            } else if (node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (node.Left == null){
                    node.Left = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * the number of elements in the tree
     * @return size.
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * The height of the tree.
     * The empty tree and the tree with only the root node both have height 0.
     * @return the height of the tree.
     */
    @Override
    public int height() {
        return countHeight(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for height
     */
    private int countHeight(Node node){
        if(node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.max(countHeight(node.getLeft()), countHeight(node.getRight()));
    }

    /**
     * The number of leaves in the tree.
     * @return the amount of leaves the tree has.
     */
    @Override
    public int leaves() {
        return countLeaves(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for leaves
     */
    private int countLeaves(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return countLeaves(node.Left) + countLeaves(node.Right);
    }


    /**
     * A string describing the tree
     * @return
     */
    public String toString(){
        String str = "[" + helpToString(root);
        if (str.length() > 1) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
        } return str + "]";
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for toString
     */
    private String helpToString(Node node) {
        String str = "";
        if (node != null) {
            str += helpToString(node.Right);
            str += node.data + ", ";
            str += helpToString(node.Left);
        }
        return str;
      }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
/**
 * Test class for a tree.
 */
public class TreeTest{
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);

    Tree<Integer> tree;
    int[] elementsInTree;
    int[] elementsNotInTree;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        /**
         * This tree should look like this:
         *
         *               8
         *             /  \
         *            3   10
         *           / \    \
         *          1   6    14
         *             / \   /
         *            4   7 13
         */
        tree = new Tree<>();
        elementsInTree = new int[] {8, 10, 14, 13, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7};
        for (int elem : elementsInTree) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }
        elementsNotInTree = new int[] {34, -3, -10, 12, 74, 5};
    }
 @Test
    public void heightIsLogOfNumLeavesTreeIsPerfect() {
        // For a perfect tree, tree.height() == log2(tree.leaves()

        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        int[] elements = new int[] {8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 9, 14};
        int numLeaves = 4;
        int logNumLeaves = (int) Math.round(Math.log(numLeaves) / Math.log(2));
        for (int elem : elements) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }

        // Act
        int height = tree.height();
        // Assert
        assertThat(height, equalTo(logNumLeaves));
    }

    @Test
    public void leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() { //TEST
        // A perfect tree has all leaves at the same depth, and all internal nodes
        // (i.e. non-leaves) have two children
        //
        // This test should assert that a perfect tree with 2*n-1 nodes total,
        // has exactly n leaves (i.e. that Tree.leaves() returns n).
        //
        // An example is the perfect three-node tree from the test above:
        //
        //                        (1338)
        //                        /    \
        //                    (1337)  (1396)

        // You have to construct your own tree here, with n >= 4
       
    Tree <Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
       int n = 4;
       for(int i = 0; i>=n; i++) {
           tree.insert(i);
         int numLeaves = 2*n-1;
         int leaves = tree.leaves();
         assertThat(leaves,equalTo(numLeaves));
       }
    }

    // Tests for insert/height
    @Test
    public void insertValuesInAscendingOrderIncrementsHeight() { //TEST
        // When inserting elements in ascending order, each element is inserted
        // to the right of the deepest node, so the height should increment by
        // 1 for each element inserted.
        Tree <Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        int val = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < val; i++){
            tree.insert(i);

        }
            int treeHeight = tree.height();
        treeHeight++;
            assertThat(tree.size(),equalTo(treeHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: @phatfingers what is missing in the construction of the tree? I am suppose to only have these method that is included.

Comment: I was referring to leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect().  It looks like you moved the closing curly brace down, maybe on accident?  You should have something like, `for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) { tree.insert(i); }`  in a closed loop, then do your assertion check outside that loop.

Comment: @phatfingers I have added a similar ( I think) test that might help. Please look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's awkward that "n" is used in the instructions to describe a tree with n leaves because "n" is traditionally used to describe your node count.  But picture a tree with 4 nodes at the bottom, then half that for the prior layer, then half again for the first layer, and you have a tree with 1+2+4 nodes, or 7 nodes total, which coincides with the formula 2*n-1 (2*4-1=7).

```
@Test
public void leavesIsCorrectWhenTreeIsPerfect() {
    int n=4;
    int[] balanced=new int[] {4,2,6,1,3,5,7};
    for (int i=0; i<balanced.length; i++) {
         tree.insert(balanced[i]);
    }
    int leaves = tree.leaves();
    assertThat(balanced.length,equalTo(2*n-1));
    assertThat(leaves,equalTo(n));
}
```

Comment: when I write like this I get a message java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: <4> but: was <5> . Why is that? However if I put int i = 1; in the for loop it works. Is that correct or not? –

Comment: My bad... I didn't notice that your tree wasn't self-balancing.  You can't just do a `tree.insert(i)` and hope for the best.

Comment: How am I supposed to do it then? Because if I add   Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>(); as the first line. I still get a problem were   Expected: <4>
     but: was <1>.

Comment: I rewrote it to insert balanced[i] instead of i.  Note that the order of the values was carefully chosen to create a balanced tree.

Comment: If you don't understand why it's balanced, you should try making your own by hand with different numbers.  Like start with 10, pick a number less and a number greater for your next two.  Draw it out on paper.  Do the same for each leaf.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i>=n; i++) {
tree.insert(i);
```

The condition of your for loop is always false.

Comment: @borazon How should I fix this?

Comment: @msss Well, since the for loop always starts at i=0, and n is 4, i>=n is never true. I didn't look at the rest of the code but this for loop will never be entered. I'm assuming you meant `i<=n`?

Comment: @barazon I have fixed this but I get a message java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: <4> but: was <5> . Why is that? However if I put int i = 1; in the for loop it works. Is that correct or not?